# Best way to implement observer pattern in Delphi

Tags: delphi, oop, design-patterns

I found different implementations of the observer pattern in Delphi, like:
[Sourcemaking Design Patterns](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer/delphi) and [Delphi Hobbyist](http://tdelphihobbyist.blogspot.com/2009/10/observer-design-pattern-in-delphi-push.html).

In general, what is the best way to implement an observer in Delphi?
I would say using interfaces because the code is more readable.

Comment: Interfaces not so much because the code becomes more readable, but because the code becomes/is more decoupled.

Comment: Here's another implementation to keep handy: http://blogs.teamb.com/joannacarter/2004/06/30/690

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no "good" or "best" way to implement patterns.
The implementation you choose depends on how you want to use it.

You could for instance also use the generics feature (available since Delphi 2009) to simplify the use of a lot of patterns.

And if you use Pre Delphi-3 versions, or want to avoid `reference counting` you cannot use interfaces.
(Reference counting can open a new can of worms when mixed with traditional Owner/Ownee based life time management; be sure to descend classes that expose interfaces from the right ancestor - like [TInterfacedObject](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/TInterfacedObject) - and watch your life time management).

Apart from the "pure" question on how to implement the observer pattern, it is also good to be able to recognize classes in Delphi that implement the observer pattern.

For instance the [TDataSet](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DB.TDataSet)/[TDataSource](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DB.TDataSource) also implement the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).
The whole concept of [Data Aware Controls](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE/en/Using_Common_Data_Control_Features) depends on it, all bound through the [TDataLink](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DB.TDataLink).

I have written a [TDataLinkReflector](http://bo.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/57889#1271339) component based on the `TDataLink`, which reflects all the virtual methods in `TDataLink` to events in `TDataLinkReflector`.

Base on `TDataLinkReflector` I wrote [TDataAwareControlController](http://bo.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/57889#1271353) components that does all kind of interesting things to Data Aware Controls based on the TDataSet, its TFields and the TDataSource linking to the TDataSet (coloring on read-only, required, etc).

But even a seemingly simple thing like events can be seen as based on that pattern (though events are single cast, so only one observer can watch one event).

Another class implementing this is the [TApplicationEvents](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/AppEvnts.TApplicationEvents); each instance lets you listen to any of the events on TApplication.

I hope that sheds some light on where the observer patterns is used in Delphi.

--jeroen

PS: Anyone interested in the components I wrote might want to see the [<s>CodeRage video mentioned here</s>](https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=114273).

Edit: companies being companies, the Embarcadero Forums and CodeCentral died and no real effort from them to put in the Internet Archive was made. With some searching I found a few ones back including [JeroenPluimers_SmarterDBCode.zip](http://altd.embarcadero.com/CodeRageIII/JeroenPluimers_SmarterDBCode.zip)

Edit 2: [@GBg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10870610/gbg) converted the video to .mp4 format. It is available through the [Wayback Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayback_Machine) at [JeroenPluimers_SmarterDBCode.mp4](https://web.archive.org/web/20230927093722if_/https://www.cevahirsoft.com/video/JeroenPluimers_SmarterDBCode.mp4)

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is dead. Would it be possible for you to provide the CodeRage link again?

Comment: Regrettably the forums server did not get archived before Borland/Inprise/Embarcadero deleted the contents. I don't have a video link any more, but you can get the code on https://github.com/jpluimers/Conferences/tree/master/2009/DelphiLive.2009/Smarter-code-with-databases-and-data-aware-controls

Comment: If the codecentral server is up, you might be able to get the video through https://wiert.me/2009/04/24/spoken-coderage-iii-december-1-5-2008-on-delphi-database-and-xml-related-topics/

Comment: I have created a component with an internal list in FMX (derived from TControl). I want to populate its list from a datasource. I hope the observer pattern and your video will help me.

Comment: I'm really busy the upcoming weeks. If you cannot find the video, let me know via Twitter or my blog (see profile at https://stackoverflow.com/users/29290/jeroen-wiert-pluimers?tab=profile).
If you found the video, please put a link in the comments to help out other people that might want to look at later.

Comment: Unfortunately, after several days of searching, I couldn't find it. In CodeRage 7, Jim Tierney created an example of TListBindSourceAdapter that didn't quite meet my needs.

Comment: @GBg please ping me on Twitter/Mastodon/Bluesky. I should have the screen recording somewhere. If you could help converting that to .mp4 that would be great.

Comment: I have updated the download locations and hints to convert the Camtasia Shockwave to mp4 at https://wiert.me/2009/04/24/spoken-coderage-iii-december-1-5-2008-on-delphi-database-and-xml-related-topics/ and will update the answer with the new download link as well.

Answer (score 2):

Good article with source code:
[An Observer / Observable implementation in Delphi using Interfaces](https://web.archive.org/web/20050204002436/http://itte.no/delphi/ObservedDemo.htm)

Comment: the link is broken :'(

Comment: There is a cached copy here: https://web.archive.org/web/20050204002436/http://itte.no/delphi/ObservedDemo.htm ;)